# SQL query returns different results when run from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

A have a query that returns different results when run directly in SQL Server Management Studio and when run from Excel (using the SQLOLEDB provider). Both return a table with 12 rows (one per month) and two columns (date and a complex count), but some of the numeric values are incorrect in the Excel result set.

I'm happy to show you the full detail, but to start with can you suggest what type of things can cause such a difference?

Versions: SQL Server 10.50.4000, Excel 2013

Edit: the full details ...

```
select cast(ActualDate as date) as 'Start of rolling 12 months'
    , count(distinct x.con_id) as 'Total Sponsors'
from DateTimeDimV4.dbo.datedim
    join (select cm_id, con_id
            , cm.start_date as activation_date
            , isnull(stop_date, getdate()) as stop_date
        from cm 
            join con_act ca on ca.con_act_db_id = cm.con_act_db_id and ca.con_act_id = cm.con_act_id
        where 
            ca.code = 'corres'
        ) X on cast(activation_date as date) <= cast(ActualDate as date) 
                and cast(stop_date as date) > cast(ActualDate as date)
where 
    --ActualDate = eomonth(ActualDate) -- only works in SQL 2012, so instead we use ...
    ActualDate = DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, ActualDate)), DATEADD(mm, 1, ActualDate))
    and ActualDate >= '31 Jul 2012' and ActualDate <= '30 June 2013'
group by cast(ActualDate as date)
order by cast(ActualDate as date)
```

In SSMS, this returns ...

```
Start of rolling 12 months  Total Sponsors
2012-07-31  862
2012-08-31  872
2012-09-30  872
2012-10-31  880
2012-11-30  876
2012-12-31  878
2013-01-31  882
2013-02-28  888
2013-03-31  887
2013-04-30  887
2013-05-31  920
2013-06-30  933
```

But in Excel I get ...

```
Start of rolling 12 months  Total Sponsors
2012-07-31  862
2012-08-31  872
2012-09-30  872
2012-10-31  880
2012-11-30  876
2012-12-31  878
2013-01-31  882
2013-02-28  887
2013-03-31  887
2013-04-30  887
2013-05-31  887
2013-06-30  887
```

Note that the first seven rows are identical but that Excel repeats the same incorrect value in the last five rows.

Also note that if I change the literal dates from '31 Jul 2012' and '30 June 2013' to '31 Jul 2011' and '30 June 2012' then the two environments produce results that are identical to each other.

Comment: You are going to need to show the full detail.  Without that, we have no idea of data types, what "incorrect" means, etc.  Please provide as much detail as possible in your question.

Comment: Incorrect meaning? values wrongly rounded, totally wrong calculation, give more detials

Comment: I have added details to the question. The code I show there is a cut-back version with as many complexities removed as I can while still showing the problem. At that level of simplicity I could most likely rephrase it without needing to use a sub-select, but I don't think that rephrasing would work for the more complex real case.

Comment: Are you putting the query directly into Excel? Like this? http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-create-pivot-table-using-sql/

Comment: If it works fine in SQL but not in Excel, I'm guessing it has to do with Excel's 'intelligent' interpretation of dates. Two things you can try: 1. Use SQL Profiler to capture and inspect the SQL that Excel is submitting. 2. Alter your query to return the date as something that looks nothing like a date, i.e. 'ZZZ20130731' and see what that does. Not a solution, just a journey towards one. Post back if you would like more details.

Comment: Yes, @joseph4tw, that's exactly how I did it (except that I chose Table rather than Pivot Table in the Import Data dialog).

Comment: @ElectricLlama: I cannot use Profiler on the production system. But when I run this on a copy of the database (which is a few months old) on a server I do have access to, I see in Profiler the exact query as shown above. And the values returned to Excel from that server are correct (i.e. SSMS and Excel agree). What does that suggest? That something is configured oddly on the production server?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: I modified query to return `'ZZZ' + cast(cast(ActualDate as date) as varchar)`. The "Total Sponsors" column showed the same values as before. So it does not seem to be that Excel is confused about the dates.

Comment: Sorry.. none if it really makes any sense. This seems like one of those things where you'll kick yourself when you work it out. I can only suggest more tests like... when you ran against a different server, did you use the exact same Excel sheet, client, version of Excel and driver and just point it at a different database? That would imply some weird database issue as that's the only difference.

Comment: @MattClarke is SSMS querying dev database and Excel using production?

Comment: It is always worth double and triple checking which db is being queried, so I did just check again. I am certain the SSMS and Excel tables are using the same query against the same database ... but returning different numbers as described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PICNIC indeed! Sorry for wasting your time.

The Excel version was executing the query against the correct server, but the wrong database. It was executing against a backup database whose name was only one character different from the live one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
and ActualDate >= '31 Jul 2012' and ActualDate <= '30 June 2013'
```

to:

```
and ActualDate >= '2012-07-31' and ActualDate <= '2013-06-30'
```

My logic: <del>I think that MS Query is interpreting the literal date differently than SSMS. I can't prove it, though, since I can't find any documentation on MS Query.</del> Scratch that. Let's just call it a hunch.

I usually stick with the ISO date formats for all my date literals.

Also, why did you abbreviate July but not June?

Comment: Nice hunch, but makes no difference.

Comment: Jun - July anomaly is just a typo. But in SSMS it makes no diference.

Comment: :) I tried. Sorry @MattClarke, Not sure what else it could be. It's an odd one.